# How to print column total directly below each column in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

My code requests the user to input array size, as well as values. I want to sum each column and display the total below each column, as in a table.

```java
int a[][] = new int[row][column];
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
        System.out.println("Number" + (j + 1 )+ ": ");
        a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        array_output.append("\t").append(a[i][j]);
    }
    array_output.append("\n");
    System.out.println("\n");
}

System.out.println("Array: ");
System.out.println(array_output);
for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
    int columnSum = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        columnSum += a[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println("Total column: " + columnSum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
String message="Total Column:";
      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      int row=2,column=3;
      StringBuilder array_output=new StringBuilder();
      int a[][] = new int[row][column];
      for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
          array_output.append(String.format("%"+message.length()+"s",""));
          for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
              System.out.println("Number" + (j + 1 )+ ": ");
              a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
              array_output.append("\t").append(a[i][j]);
          }
          array_output.append("\n");
          System.out.println("\n");
      }

      System.out.println("Array: ");
      System.out.println(array_output);
      System.out.print(message+" \t");
      for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
          int columnSum = 0; 
          for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
              columnSum += a[i][j];
          }
          System.out.print(columnSum+"\t");
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice only the additional changes that added on top of your code snippet.

> ```
>     int a[][] = new int[row + 1][column]; // +1 for total/sum
>
>     for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
>         //... rest of the logic correct
>         a[row][j] = columnSum;
>     }
>
>     //Print the result
>     for (int i=0; i < row+1; i++) {
>         for (int j=0; j < column; j++) {
>             System.out.print(a[i][j] + "\t");
>         }
>         System.out.println();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the same variable `columnSum` in each interation. If you want a sum for each column then `columnSum` needs to be an array with an entry for each column. Then you can print that array as last output row.

I recommend to give the variables `i` and `j` a more meaningful name. Call `row` `rows` and `i` row and you can read you code more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I understand correctly, you suggest that the output of each sum should be displayed in an array? Should that array form part of the array above, or must it be a 1D array of the same length as the 2D array?

Comment: Just add an array `columnSums`size row `int[] columnSums = new int[row]` before the last loop. Inside your loop you then assign `columnSum[j]=columnSum;` before the next iteration of the outer loop. This array contains a sum for each column which in turn you can print in a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array of result. Now while entering data in input array, prepare your result array by adding column data in result array. In last print it. It will same time and 1 extra for loop.

```
   int a[][] = new int[row][column];
    int result[] = new int[column];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++){
            System.out.println("Number" + (j + 1 )+ ": ");
            a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            array_output.append("\t").append(a[i][j]);
            result[j] = result[j]+a[i][j];//creating array of column sum
        }
        array_output.append("\n");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    System.out.println("Array: ");
    System.out.println(array_output);
    for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++){
       System.out.print(result[j] + "\\t");
    }
```